# Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type [java.lang.String]:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

i am trying to create pooling connection of Database in jdbc below is my code but i am getting

error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource#0' defined in class path resource [resources/database/Database.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type [java.lang.String]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

i am using hibernate to save data in database if my method is wrong how to create pooling of connections for JDBC Database connections

database.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">



<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" /> 
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:xml-config" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls remove bean declaration of DriverManagerDataSource and include following to use the pooled dataSource via jdbcTemplate :-

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: getting java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.h2.Driver from ClassLoader:WebappClassLoader
  context: /userinfo
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@6193b845
;ClassLoader:WebappClassLoader
  context: /userinfo
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/

Comment: Seems you havent included H2 library to your project. Pls use this on your pom.xml :-                                                                                <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.140</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: its working but i if i try to execute a sql statement i am getting  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "TOKEN" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: i am executing command list = getHibernateTemplate().find(
                "from TokenModel where UserID=?",userid);

Comment: It seems issue with the H2 URL. Can you check this link (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) and validate your URL is good with it. The schema related specifically.

Comment: how to give url to connect to a local database

Comment: i have given url as jdbc:h2:mysql://localhost:3306/token

Comment: i fixed  i have given value for other database so i am wrong